# how can i make image slider like square(squareup.com)?

Tags: jquery, carousel

I wanna make a jquery image slider like one in squareup.com
is there any image slider plug-in like this? 
I mean the one not limited on both left and right side.
or could you give me the way to modify the other plug in to do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its a full screen jquery slider with Contents. You can find some good examples on internet with "Jquery Division Sliders". Or have a look at this link :

[**Large Slider**](http://www.musca.se/full-window-width-jquery-tools-content-slider-demo/)

This is not exactly the same thing, but you can customize it on this website. And to integrate it to your website, obviously you have to make some custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

There all plenty of the image slider plugins available for free download.
eg.

1. [wowslider](http://wowslider.com)
2. [nivoSlider](http://nivoslider.com)

This article will help you: [20 unique and creative image sliders](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/02/18/20-unique-and-creative-image-sliders/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like [this](http://gilbert.pellegrom.me/demo/square-slider/). It's cross browser compliant, but you will have to make some modifications for it to work in older browsers.